# SwiftUI store View as a variable while passing it some bindings

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to store a `View` as a variable for later use, while passing that `View` some `Bindings`.
Here's what I've tried:

```
struct Parent: View {
    @State var title: String? = ""
    var child: Child!

    init() {
        self.child = Child(title: self.$title)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            child
            //...
            Button(action: {
                self.child.f()    
            }) {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Child: View {
    @Binding var title: String?

    func f() {
        // complex work from which results a string
        self.title = <that string>
    }

    var body: some View {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It compiles correctly and the `View` shows as expected, however when updating from the child the passed `Binding` from the parent, the variable never gets updated. You can even do something like this (from the child):

```
self.title = "something"
print(self.title) // prints the previous value, in this case nil
```

I don't know if this is a bug or not, but directly initializing the child in the `body` property does the trick. However, I need that child as a property to access its methods.

Comment: Don't you want to use ObservableObject it will be passed by reference and such problem should gone?

Comment: @Asperi I want the Child to be stored as a variable because it contains some functions that I want to call from the parent

Comment: I understood about Child, I meant instead of `@State`.

Comment: @Asperi wouldn't it be the same thing as using `@State` in this case? I mean, I still pass a reference to the variable by using `$title`

Comment: I wanna say there should be a better way if you want to store `child` as you do now. Doing so usually will lead to a pattern break which brings unnecessary job for later maintaince.

Comment: @E.Coms and do you know what that way is?

Answer (score 0):

This is counter to the design of the SwiftUI framework. You should not have any persistent view around to call methods on. Instead, views are created and displayed as needed in response to your app's state changing.

Encapsulate your data in an `ObservableObject` model, and implement any methods you need to call on that model.

**Update**

It is fine to have such a function defined in `Child`, but you should only be calling it from within the `Child` struct definition. For instance, if your child view contains a button, that button can call the child's instance methods. For example,

```
struct Parent: View {
    @State private var number = 1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(number)")
            Child(number: $number)
        }
    }
}

struct Child: View {
    @Binding var number: Int

    func double() {
        number *= 2
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.double()
            }) {
                Text("Double")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you wouldn't try to call `double()` from *outside* the child struct. If you wanted a function that can be called globally, put it in a data model. This is especially true if the function call is making network requests, as the model will stick around outside your child view, even if it is recreated due to layout changing.

```
class NumberModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var number = 1

    func double() {
        number *= 2
    }
}

struct Parent: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = NumberModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(model.number)")

            Button(action: {
                self.model.double()
            }) {
                Text("Double from Parent")
            }

            Child(model: model)
        }
    }
}

struct Child: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: NumberModel

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.model.double()
            }) {
                Text("Double from Child")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have updated my question with more code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change something from Parent for the child, binding is the right way. If that's complicated, you have to use DataModel.

```
struct Parent: View {
@State var title: String? = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Child(title: $title)
        Button(action: {
            self.title = "something"
        }) {
           Text("click me")
        }
    }
}
}

 struct Child: View {
@Binding var title: String?
var body: some View {
    Text(title ?? "")
}
}
```

Comment: I've provided a basic example in my question, but in my app it involves doing complex work, including network calls, that's why I have to call the function

Comment: View is view. The network data handling is not a view, right? You can do it in DataModel, then put a holder in the View, or link to view through ViewModel if data is very complicated.